# Unable to load .js files after Windows 10 1903 upgrade

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

Tonight my computer installed the latest Windows10 upgrade (1903)

Now my localhost web site fails to load ANY Javascript files (JQuery, my own, vendor's etc)

All I get is net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET from every attempt to load a .js file

The problem is independent of browser.

I am running Nginx and MariaDB

Any help appreciated

Thanks

UPDATE:
Today I installed a new serverstack on a linux m/c, copied all my project to it and it worked as expected.
So I took the plunge and uninstalled my Windows stack, re-installed it with a later setup (still Njinx.PHP7/MariaDB) and I was as square one - still no JS files will load - must be a W10 issue somewhere.

Further update:
3rd party pages running on localhost (e.g. Adminer) are having the same problem, so it is definitely not my code. In fact css files are failing to load too. I am stumped.  Seems to be some problem between W10 and the localhost server - now wondering whether to try Apache and see if the problem remains - surely it is something simple though!!

Comment: Have you checked the nginx access/error logs?

Comment: Nothing in the error logs.

Comment: Access log just has lots of lines like this:- 127.0.0.1 - - [25/Sep/2019:23:20:06 +0100] "GET /JSlibs/jquery-3.2.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 65536 "http://localhost/Start.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36" "-"

Comment: I am seeing the  net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET messages in the DevTools console window (F12)

Comment: Strange, seems Nginx successfully served the file. Could antivirus/security software be interfering? Can you try from powershell with `invoke-webrequest`?

Comment: I am happy to try anything at the moment - but not at all sure how to do that - I looked up invoke-webrequest and could not make a lot of sense of it.

Comment: Assuming its an HTTP request run `Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri http://127.0.0.1/JSlibs/jquery-3.2.1.min.js` from a powershell or ISE window. Have you tried (temporarily) disabling Windows Defender or any Antivirus/Security software?

Comment: After various re-installs (including trying Apache) I am back to a basic nginx/PHP7 install (not a bundle) but still having the same problem.

Comment: result from Mister Smith's suggestion was:
invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
At line:1 char:1
+ invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri http://127.0.0.1/JSlibs/jquer ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: If I run localhost/phpinfo.php I get only the first part of the phpinfo displayed, no detail for each extension etc.